# Which one is the best for the user, button or icon for the "Close" in dialog/modal?

Tags: website-design, experience, dialog, modal

I'm designing a dialog/modal for my mobile app, which one will be the best practice for "close" on the dialog?

1."Close" button on the bottom left after the content
[image]

2."X" on the top right corner

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each one has its advantage.
in close button

- it is easily identifiable.
- easy to click.

in cross button

- doesn't occupy much space.

I suppose you can go with a cross icon as in almost 70% cases **while closing a modal the user clicks on blank space** rather than clicking on close button or icon for closing it. as it is easy to do rather than clicking on specific area.